# Gitlab clone private repo using api

Tags: gitlab

```
git clone https://gitlab.com:<private token>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

Trying to clone private repository I have error " fatal: Authentication failed "

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you have created a Personal Access Token on your Gitlab account with access to api scope. Also, the token must be not expired.

I used this and worked for me:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com:<personal_access_token>@gitlab.com/user/repo.git'
```

FYI: I haven't set up Two-Factor Authentication (2FA), maybe this could be your problem if you have set 2FA in your account.

Comment: This approach works like a charm. If you have enabled Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) it will work as long as tokens rights will be set to "api".

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the private token is used for a `gitlab-ci-token`:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:<private token>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

See [this issue for instance](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2658).

Answer (score 0):

The gitlab has a lot token, the **private token**, the **Personal Access Token**, the **CI/CD running token**,
I only just test the Persion Access Token using ***GitLab Community Edition 10.1.2***, the example:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${Personal Access Tokens}@gitlab.com/username/myrepo.git
```